# Loading multiple textbox value to datagridview

Tags: c#

The following code gives me to take one row value from textbox to datagridview ......

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Course Name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Credit", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add(txtName.Text.Trim(), txtCredit.Text.Trim());
addcrsView.DataSource = table;

}
```

When I give another value to textbox it just replaces the previous one. But I need to take both in datagrid view.

As I am very beginner please put your answer details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make `table` as class level object.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
```

And, set the DataGridView datasource in the `Form_Load` event

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    table.Columns.Add("Course Name", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Credit", typeof(string));
    addcrsView.DataSource = table;
}
```

Your `button1_Click` just need to add row

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    table.Rows.Add(txtName.Text.Trim(), txtCredit.Text.Trim());
}
```

Comment: would you please tell me how can I save this multiple value from gridview to database.....                                                           @Tun Zarni Kyaw                                          thanks in advace

Comment: Okay, if it works, then click the **tick** beside the answer. ... For saving multiple values to database, post a new question